# Do Project Euler questions belong here or on a different SE (or nowhere)?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

After a year and a half of no forward progress, I'm finally regaining interest in [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/), which is a series of programming/problem-solving/math challenges. As the Project Euler FAQ puts it:

> Project Euler is a series of challenging mathematical/computer programming problems that will require more than just mathematical insights to solve. Although mathematics will help you arrive at elegant and efficient methods, the use of a computer and programming skills will be required to solve most problems.

Obviously, if I have a question about the programming required to solve a PE challenge, it belongs on Stack Overflow. Similarly, if I have a question about the mathematics underlying the challenge, I should be asking it on Math.SE. But what if I have a question about the process of solving a challenge?

For example, here is the actual question I was considering asking, which led to this meta question:

---

**Should I just brute-force [Problem 11](http://projecteuler.net/problem=11)?**
Other than checking to see if any of the four digits in the equation are zero, I don't see any good way to avoid calculating the product of each 4-item sequence in the block. Is brute force the 'right' solution, or should I be looking deeper? Problem 11 is pretty early on, I don't know if I'm making things harder than they need to be.

---

The Gaming FAQ says "puzzle solving" questions are on-topic, and I think Project Euler is *probably* a game (because I can't think of an argument that disqualifies Project Euler which doesn't also disqualify [SpaceChem](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spacechem)), so...

**Are Project Euler questions that relate to the process of solving the puzzles on topic?**

Comment: It's not a game.

Comment: Nope. Maybe some are good for comp sci/programmers though

Comment: @RavenDreamer - Can you explain in more detail why you think that? (My intent is not to argue, just to understand)

Comment: Disregard that, it's not relevant. I'll delete the comment when I'm on an actual PC.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Project Euler is not a video game (the most basic way to describe the "games" that are on-topic here), and as such isn't on-topic here. Just like board games and tabletop games aren't on-topic here.

High-level, conceptual questions in programming—whatever the context—like your example are generally on-topic for [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com). A [cursory search](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=euler) on Programming Puzzles and Code Golf.SE indicates they're also [on-topic there](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16/what-are-the-policies-for-threads-relating-to-facebook-puzzles-project-euler-u), as well.

Comment: I did not know that site was in beta! Thanks!

Comment: I don't think how to solve PE questions would be on-topic at Programmers as that deals with softer questions (there aren't any there currently I can find), but rather SO (for implementation details) or Math.SE (for theory)

Comment: @NickT As a former moderator and the person who [wrote the current version of the FAQ](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/2424/8), I assure you that Programmers is the correct place for help with conceptual programming problems, not Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is [when you have a specific issue regarding code you've written, not when you're trying to design the program](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/introducing-programmers-stackexchange-com/).